# Project management with Visual Studio, without TFS?

Tags: visual-studio, project-management

Can I have some basic project management in Visual Studion without TFS or is TFS what I need?

Basically I like to get a list with my projects, last edited dates, and if possible project tags (customer for example), and when selecting one VS should load it. From the right repository (Mercurial/Git/Svn). I can move my project to some repo host if they have this solution (Addon).

At the moment I handle the projecs manually with Windows standard folders + SVN/Hg in folder context menu, and thats a headache.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know Visual Studio doesn't support that functionality natively.

TFS isn't my forte but I know it comes with MSDN subscriptions and the retail version is around $500 if that is the path you are interested in.  If you do go the TFS route you have an option to use TFS Basic during install which is a greatly simplified install of TFS that can even use SQL Express.

You can check out pricing and download the trial from here if you want more info:
http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/team-foundation-server